# How to use v-model even if user does not edits the input value?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, post, v-model

I am just learning vue.js.

I have an input, where I want to have already filled field `value="{{ current_user.rbe.main_contact_person }}"`. The user should be able to edit the value. I am trying to send the data with v-model. It only works if an user edits something, but if not it will send nothing.

How could I send the value to database even if it is not edited?

I am using jinja2 and that's why I am using curly brackets`value="{{ current_user.rbe.main_contact_person }}"`.

```
             <input 
                class="fieldInput"
                placeholder= "{{ current_user.rbe.main_contact_person }}"
                value="{{ current_user.rbe.main_contact_person }}"
                v-model="newContract.name"
              >
```

Comment: At what exact moment do you wish to send a value to DB? Some event or something else?

Comment: @anatoly I have a submit button in the end and it sends also other data. I am using `new FormData` and appending the properties.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the value. simply give the value of `{{ current_user.rbe.main_contact_person }}` to `newContract.name`.